# Making Python code more compact and efficient

Tags: python, performance, loops, consolidation

I have the following code, which basically load some data files that I have in different folders, take an average of every repeat at each Temperature and then plot the results. The code works fine, and it was OK when I had only a couple of set of data. But now I have 9 different set of temperature each with 5 repeat each and the code is becoming too long in my opinion. Is there a way to consolidate it? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

steps    = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/1st/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[0])


# T = 303 K

msd303_1 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/1st/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd303_2 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/2nd/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd303_3 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/3rd/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd303_4 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/4th/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd303_5 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/5th/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])

msd303 = np.vstack((msd303_1,msd303_2,msd303_3,msd303_4,msd303_5)).T
msd303_mean = np.mean(msd303,axis=1)
msd303_std = np.std(msd303,axis=1)

# T = 313 K

msd313_1 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/313K/1st/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd313_2 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/313K/2nd/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd313_3 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/313K/3rd/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd313_4 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/313K/4th/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
msd313_5 = np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/313K/5th/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])

msd313 = np.vstack((msd313_1,msd313_2,msd313_3,msd313_4,msd313_5)).T
msd313_mean = np.mean(msd313,axis=1)
msd313_std = np.std(msd313,axis=1)


plt.yscale("log")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.plot(steps,msd303_mean)
plt.plot(steps,msd313_mean)
```

Comment: use a function.

Comment: Make a function that takes the string part after `nvt` and the column number, and returns the result of `np.loadtxt`. That should simplify things a bit.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you may be downvoted because stackoverflow is not the right place to code review (it is used not to improve the code but to solve issues). You can use this instead : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CorentinLimier Thanks, I did not know abot codereview!

Answer (score 0):

```
np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/1st/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
```

Since you run this a lot, try replacing with

```py
def load(pos):
    return np.loadtxt('/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/'+pos+'/Average_MSD.txt',usecols=[1])
```

Then using `msd303_1 = load('1st')`. Not a huge improvement but more readable.

Comment: If you're working with a current Python version you could use an f-string: `f'/home/aperego/data/HexaPaper/nvt/303K/{pos}/Average_MSD.txt'`